# I’m having error when I install tor on kali linux

Tags: linux

I’m having error when I install `tor` on kali linux

```sh
root@r00txh:~# apt-get install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
tracker-miner-fs : Breaks: rygel (< 0.40.1-3~) but 0.36.2-4 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: The error message states that installing `tor` is prevented due to a versioning conflict related to `rygel`. It also mentions `tracker-miner-fs` as having something to with the issue. You might wish to clarify your question with your thoughts on those packages?

Comment: How can I fix this issue:
(The following packages have unmet dependencies), so Ican install tor.
I have to install to service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot solve the "The following packages have unmet dependencies" issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1555536/cannot-solve-the-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies-issue)